# tkinter does not properly display data with check buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making something like a "to-do list" with check buttons that indicate the task's status (`done` or `to-do`). Check button makes callback and change status. I think everything connected with 'backyard' works. When I click the button, the status in the object changes, but it doesn't display properly.

When I display a list of tasks for the first time, it displays everything correctly, but trouble comes up when I add another task to the existing list and display it. I figure out that maybe somehow it overwrites task on existing objects, but honestly, I have no clue how to fix this...

Here is the code:

c_body (file with class):

```
import datetime

class CalendarObj:
    def __init__(self, task, date, time, stat = False):
        self.task = task
        self.stat = stat
        self.date = date
        self.time = time
    def displayObj(self):
        return self.task + ' ' +  self.date  + ' ' + self.time
    def nowDate():
        date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d %B")
        return date
    def nowTime():
        time = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H:%M")
        return time
```

c_view:

```
import c_body
from tkinter import *

calendar = []
status = []
checkbuttons = []
textlist = []

def config():
    global listback, main_root, button_display_list, button_add_task, button_delete_task, button_delete_all_done, button_exit_app
    main_root = Tk()
    main_root.title('Lista zadan')
    main_root.geometry("500x500")
    button_display_list = Button(main_root, text='Display Tasks', width=12, command=display)
    button_display_list.grid(column=0, row=4)
    button_add_task = Button(main_root, text='Add Task', width=12, command=add)
    button_add_task.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button_delete_task = Button(main_root, text='Delete Task', width=12)
    button_delete_task.grid(column=0, row=1)
    button_delete_all_done = Button(main_root, text='Delete All Done', width=12)
    button_delete_all_done.grid(column=0, row=2)
    button_exit_app = Button(main_root, text='EXIT', width=12, command=exit_window)
    button_exit_app.grid(column=0, row=3)

def exit_window():
    main_root.destroy()

def add():
    global task, button_add
    insert_root = Tk()
    insert_root.title('Dodaj zadanie:')
    task = Entry(insert_root, width=80)
    task.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def add_task():
        global task_obj, calendar
        date = c_body.CalendarObj.nowDate()
        time = c_body.CalendarObj.nowTime()
        task_obj = c_body.CalendarObj(task.get(), date, time)
        calendar.append(task_obj)
        insert_root.destroy()

    button_add = Button(insert_root, text='dodaj zadanie', command=add_task)
    button_add.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E, padx=20, pady=20)
    insert_root.mainloop()

def callback_on_checkbutton_click():
    print("One of the Checkbuttons clicked!")
    for i in range(len(calendar)):
        print('\tOld calendar[' + str(i) + '] state: ' + calendar[i].displayObj())
        calendar[i].stat = status[i].get()
        print('\t\tNew calendar[' + str(i) + '] state: ' + calendar[i].displayObj())

def display():
    for i in range(len(calendar)):
        lp = i + 1
        print("status dla:", lp, calendar[i].stat)
        x = (str(lp) + '. ' + calendar[i].displayObj())
        textlist.append(x)
        status.append(BooleanVar())
        if calendar[i].stat == False:
            print("display() called. For index i: ", i, ' setting checkbutton value to checked (onvalue=0)')
            status[i].set(False)
        elif calendar[i].stat == True:
            print("display() called. For index i: ", i, ' setting checkbutton value to unchecked (offvalue=1)')
            status[i].set(True)
        checkbuttons.append(
            Checkbutton(
                master=main_root,
                text=textlist[i],
                variable=status[i],
                onvalue=True,
                offvalue=False,
                command=callback_on_checkbutton_click
            )
        )
        checkbuttons[i].grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=W)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config()
    main_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is 'backyard'? How does it not display properly?

Comment: Multiple calls to `Tk()` cause Tk Vars to not work (without a lot of extra effort).  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: Add `master=main_root` to `BooleanVar()`.

Comment: So what is the best way to erase displayed tasks (expired data), and display updated data?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

1. First of all, `textlist.append` and `status.append` need to be moved to function `add(). Becouse everytime when I display data it appends unnecessarily additional positions to my list.
2. Before using function `display()`, list with `checkbuttons` need to be cleared. In previous version of that function it was adding `checkbuttons` to existing data, everytime when iteration was called. In short way: container with data must be cleared before displaying new data.

Here is code with my fixes and changes:

```
def add():
    global task, button_add
    insert_root = Toplevel()
    insert_root.title('Dodaj zadanie:')
    task = Entry(insert_root, width=80)
    task.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)
    def add_task():
        global task_obj, calendar
        date = c_body.CalendarObj.nowDate()
        time = c_body.CalendarObj.nowTime()
        task_obj = c_body.CalendarObj(task.get(), date, time)
        calendar.append(task_obj)
        textlist.append(StringVar())
        status.append(BooleanVar())
        insert_root.destroy()
    button_add = Button(insert_root, text='dodaj zadanie', command=add_task)
    button_add.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E, padx=20, pady=20)
    insert_root.mainloop()

def display():
    global calendar, textlist, status, checkbuttons
    checkbuttons.clear()
    for i in range(len(calendar)):
        lp = i + 1
        print("status dla:", lp, calendar[i].stat)
        x = (str(lp) + '. ' + calendar[i].displayObj())
        textlist[i].set(x)
        if calendar[i].stat == False:
            print("display() called. For index i: ", i, ' setting checkbutton value to checked (onvalue=0)')
            status[i].set(False)
        elif calendar[i].stat == True:
            print("display() called. For index i: ", i, ' setting checkbutton value to unchecked (offvalue=1)')
            status[i].set(True)
        checkbuttons.append(
            Checkbutton(
                master=main_root,
                textvariable=textlist[i],
                variable=status[i],
                onvalue=True,
                offvalue=False,
                command=callback_on_checkbutton_click
            )
        )
        checkbuttons[i].grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky=W)
```